# How to get present number of inserts/widgets in an overlay?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created flat buttons that hide or show widget by inserting and removing widget in overlay.
And if I keep pressing the hide button even after there are no more widgets left in overlay, I get

```
'_overlay != null': is not true.
```

Now, I wish to add a check in there but I didn't find any way to check present number of widgets in Overlay stack.
Any help?

```
void showOverlayEntry() {
    createOverlayEntry();
    Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry);
  }

void removeOverlayEntry() {
//wish to add a check here if there are no more inserts left to remove
    overlayEntry.remove();
  }
```

Comment: Can you post some of your codes?